# Vault failed to connect timeout

Tags: curl, timeout, hashicorp-vault

I have a Hasicorp Vault server running and when I do a curl request on it locally using the command below I get an error (below).

When I run the command `curl -H "X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN" $VAULT_ADDR/v1/secret/keys` it works fine on the vault server but when I do it from my laptop it gives me the error.

Both `$VAULT_TOKEN` and `$VAULT_ADDR` are set properly on local machine.

**Error**

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to example.com port 8200: Operation timed out
```

**/etc/vault.hcl**

```
backend "file" {
        path = "/var/lib/vault"
        scheme = "http"
        redirect_addr = "http://example.com:8200"
        VAULT_ADDR = "http://example.com:8200"
}

listener "tcp" {
        address = "0.0.0.0:8200"
        tls_disable = 0
        tls_cert_file = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"
        tls_key_file = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue didn't end up being anything to do with vault but instead was a firewall issue with port `8200` blocked on Azure.